# Prove that if $\underline{a}:\mathbb{N}\to A$ is a sequence such that $\underline{a}\to a$ with $a\in A$, then $h \circ \underline{a} \to h(a)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Where $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are continuous functions and $h:A\to C$ is the composition function $h = g\circ f$.

I do not have an attempt for this problem, I looking for any guidance as to where to start.

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ metric spaces, or are they simply subsets of $\Bbb R$?  Is your definition of continuity the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition?

Comment: $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{B}$ are subsets $\mathbb{R}$ and that is my defintion of continuity !

Comment: You really should put your actual question in the body of your post. The title is not the right place for it. Spread out between the title and body is even worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of convergence, your proof is going to start something like this:

> Fix any $\epsilon > 0$.

And end something like this

> Thus, for all $n > N$, we have $|h(\underline{a}(n)) - h(a)| < \epsilon$

The real question is how to bridge the gap.  Given an $\epsilon > 0$, how can we guarantee that there's an $N \in \Bbb N$ big enough so that $n>N$ means that $h(\underline{a}(n))$ is "less than $\epsilon$" away from $h(a)$?

Because $\underline{a}$ converges to $a$, we can choose an $N$ large enough to make it so that whenever $n > N$, $\underline{a}(n)$ is as close as we want to $a$.  Because of continuity, we know that if $|\underline{a}(n) - a|$ is small enough, $|h(\underline{a}(n)) - h(a)|$ will be smaller than $\epsilon$.  All together, we can choose an $N$ big enough so that whenever $n>N$, $|\underline{a}(n) - a|$ is small enough to ensure that $|h(\underline{a}(n)) - h(a)| < \epsilon$, whatever $\epsilon$ happens to be.

Now, try to express that formally, using the definition of continuity.

**Hint:** There exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that whenever $n>N$, $|\underline{a}(n) - a| < \delta$.  But what do I mean by $\delta$?